# how to change Excel view

Tags: excel

I am wondering for some very silly problem! I have saved my data files in csv format in Excel. However, all of a sadden all of my saved csv files looking as indicated below. How I would change to normal view?
Best,
Amare
[image: hoe the file looking]

Comment: What is the normal view?

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you mean you 'split into columns' when you say 'normal view'.

Check your regional settings:

> Control Panel > Clock and region > 'Change date, time or number
> formats' > Additional settings > (Numbers Tab) - look at list
> separator is equal to ","

Another option you can try is checking if the associated is correct for the file type. Search for file associations, under csv search for Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File